# Problem letting 2nd floating div filling out the rest of the horizontal space within container div

Tags: css, html, css-float, space

As the title explains, I have one container div, containing two floating divs of varying widths. See it in action here (it's the "Hotel booking" part):

http://experiencerapanui.com/book_hotel.php?hotel_id=3

I bordered the 2nd div for you. I need this 2nd div to fill out all the remaining space of the container div. I cannot fix the width of the first div, since the width of it varies depending on what the different hotels offer, but I still want the 2nd div (where the prices will appear) to fill out all the remaining space, to not make it so cramped.

How is this result achieved?

Comment: Can you put the pertinent code into this question?  Without it, this question won't be useful to anyone else once you've resolved the issue on your live site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your "bordered `div`", remove `float: left` and add `overflow: hidden`.

For a demo and explanation, see: [Fill the space of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410065/fill-the-space-of-a-div/6410231#6410231)

---

I just checked your page with IE. You don't have a doctype, so your page is hopelessly broken thanks to [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Resolve this second problem by *adding* this (the HTML5 doctype) as the very first line of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: At last, a solution that works! Works perfectly, thanks a lot!
And about the doctype, I've been wondering about IE acting strange =), thanks again!